# SQL Mirroring Witness server Corrupted

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

The witness server on my environment is corrupted and the mirrored database failed over to the secondary server. I removed database from Principal server, hoping that I can set up mirroring between the Mirror and Principal. So I backed up the database on Mirror, and restored it on the Principal; Configured mirroring on the Mirror and when I click start mirroring I got the following error message

> Alter failed for the database xxx , An exception occurred while
> executing a Transact SQL Statement or Batch.. Database 'xxx' is not
> configured for database mirroring. Error 1416

I am guessing the error happened as I didn't remove the previous mirror configuration.

How can I remove my previous mirror config and setup a mirroring between these.

when i execute this
SELECT role_desc, state_desc FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints

results
PARTNER     STARTED

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER ENDPOINT endPointName STATE = STOPPED;
```

will stop the mirroring.

```sql
DROP ENDPOINT endPointName;
```

will drop the end points. Run this on both primary and mirror.